# R programming: return ggplot object instead of grob?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating an R package. I have a function that returns a list of plots. The plots are constructed with a complex layout using functions including `gridExtra::gtable_cbind`. This returns a list of `gtable` objects. I would like the user to be able to render one of the plots by simply calling `output[[1]]` or similar (i.e. I don't want them to have to load any other packages to render the plot in the plotting pane). However the `gtable` object requires a call to `grid::grid.draw(output[[1]])` to draw.

I have tried solutions like `ggpubr::as_ggplot()` but this is cumbersome and causes a `Warning message: In diff.default(xscale) : reached elapsed time limit` for more complex layouts.

Is there a simple solution for this problem?

### reproducible example

This example is simpler so does not tend to return the time limit warning.

#### returning list of gtables

```
my_fn1 <- function() {
  
  iris_list <- split(iris, iris$Species)
  plots_laidout <- list()
  
  for (yvar in c('Sepal.Length', 'Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width')) {
  
  plot_list <- lapply(iris_list, function(dat) ggplot2::ggplotGrob(ggplot2::ggplot(dat, ggplot2::aes_string(x = 'Sepal.Length', y = yvar)) + ggplot2::geom_point()))
  
  plots_laidout[[length(plots_laidout) + 1]] <- do.call(gridExtra::gtable_cbind, plot_list)
  
  }
  
  return(plots_laidout)
  
}

output1 <- my_fn1()
grid::grid.draw(output1[[1]])
```

#### returning list of coerced ggplots

```
my_fn2 <- function() {
  
  iris_list <- split(iris, iris$Species)
  plots_laidout <- list()
  
  for (yvar in c('Sepal.Length', 'Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width')) {
    
    plot_list <- lapply(iris_list, function(dat) ggplot2::ggplotGrob(ggplot2::ggplot(dat, ggplot2::aes_string(x = 'Sepal.Length', y = yvar)) + ggplot2::geom_point()))
    
    plots_laidout[[length(plots_laidout) + 1]] <- ggpubr::as_ggplot(do.call(gridExtra::gtable_cbind, plot_list))
    
  }
  
  return(plots_laidout)
  
}

output2 <- my_fn2()
output2[[1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you want special behaviour of printing the object your function returns, you can wrap it in an S3 class and write a custom print method for it. In this case, the print method would then plot the outcome.

```r
library(ggplot2)

my_fn <- function() {
  
  iris_list <- split(iris, iris$Species)
  plots_laidout <- list()
  
  for (yvar in c('Sepal.Length', 'Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width')) {
    
    plot_list <- lapply(iris_list, function(dat) ggplot2::ggplotGrob(
      ggplot2::ggplot(dat, ggplot2::aes_string(x = 'Sepal.Length', y = yvar)) + 
        ggplot2::geom_point()
    ))
    
    plot_list <- do.call(gridExtra::gtable_cbind, plot_list)

    # Set new class
    class(plot_list) <- c("my_class", class(plot_list))
    
    plots_laidout[[length(plots_laidout) + 1]] <- plot_list
    
  }
  
  return(plots_laidout)
  
}

# Define an S3 print method
print.my_class <- function(x, newpage = TRUE) {
  if (newpage) {
    grid::grid.newpage()
  }
  grid::grid.draw(x)
  invisible(x)
}

output <- my_fn()

# Outputs plot when printing elements of output
output[[1]]
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: For creating packages, is there any disadvantage to using S3 class versus S4?

Comment: You can use S4 if you want. But changing how an object is printed doesn't require any of the special features of S4, so it would be easier to do S3 as S4 is quite formal with declaring classes and methods. If you use S4 elsewhere in the package, it might make more sense to use it.

Comment: If you'd like to know more about S3 and S4 and their differences, Hadley Wickham's book  has a good intro: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html